# SQL JOIN: Select Records from Another Table With Matching IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having trouble building a correct `SQL JOIN` statement to select some records from another table.

```
--Table Product:
ID
Name
CatID1
CatID2
```

and

```
--Table Category:
CatID
CategoryName
```

`Product.CatID1`, `Product.CatID2` are referenced to `Category.CatID`

So I really want to select `Product` fields and replace `Product.CatID1`, `Product.CatID2` with `Category.CategoryName` (for `Product.CatID1`) and  `Category.CategoryName` (for `Product.CatID2`).

This obviously does not work but explains what I need:

```
SELECT Product.ID, Product.Name, 
       Category.CategoryName as Product.CatID1, 
       Category.CategoryName as Product.CatID2 
from product, categories;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a double `LEFT JOIN` to `categories` table:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, 
       c1.CategoryName as CatID1, 
       c2.CategoryName as CatID2 
from product AS p 
LEFT JOIN categories AS c1 ON p.CatID1 = c1.CatID
LEFT JOIN categories AS c2 ON p.CatID2 = c2.CatID
```

If there is no match for either `CatID1` or `CatID2`, the corresponding field in the `SELECT` clause is going to be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Product.ID, 
Product.Name, 
C1.CategoryName as Product.CatID1, 
C2.CategoryName as Product.CatID2 
FROM Product JOIN  Category C1 ON C1.CatID = CatID1
JOIN  Category C2 ON C2.CatID = CatID2 ;
```

Use the category table twice.

What if you decide, in the future, that a product can be in 3 categories? Really, you should have a joining table for these and remove the repeating info from Product.

Comment: As per Giorgos's answer, two left joins would be better, but the observation about the many-to-many JOIN is important

Comment: Yes, having two CatID columns is usually a bad idea.